# Rust - the trait `StdError` is not implemented for `OsString`

Tags: rust

I'm writing some Rust code which uses the `?` operator. Here is a few lines of that code:

```
fn files() -> Result<Vec<std::string::String>, Box<Error>> {

    let mut file_paths: Vec<std::string::String> = Vec::new();
    ...
    file_paths.push(pathbuf.path().into_os_string().into_string()?);
    ...
    Ok(file_paths)
}
```

However, even though I'm using `?` on a `Result` it is giving me the following error:

```
`the trait `StdError` is not implemented for `OsString`.
```

This is contrary to the Rust documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html), which states that:

`The ? is shorthand for the entire match statements we wrote earlier. In other words, ? applies to a Result value, and if it was an Ok, it unwraps it and gives the inner value. If it was an Err, it returns from the function you're currently in.`

I've confirmed that pathbuf.path().into_os_string().into_string() is of type `Result`, because when I remove the `?`, I get the following compiler error:

```
expected struct `std::string::String`, found enum `std::result::Result`
```

(since file_paths is a Vector of strings, not Results).

Is this a bug with the Rust language or documentation?

In fact I tried this without pushing to the Vector, but simply initializing a variable with the value of `pathbuf.path().into_os_string().into_string()?`, and I got the same error.

Comment: What is the `Error` type you're trying to return? It's likely that `OsString` cannot be converted into it, since `into_string` returns the original `OsString` in case of an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function [OsString::into_string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.into_string) is a little unusual. It returns a `Result<String, OsString>` - so the `Err` variant is actually not an error.

In the event that the `OsString` cannot be converted into a regular string, then the `Err` variant is returned, containing the original string.

Unfortunately this means you cannot use the `?` operator directly. However, you can use `map_err` to map the error variant into an actual error, like this:

```rust
file_paths.push(
    pathbuf.path()
    .into_os_string()
    .into_string().
    .map_err(|e| InvalidPathError::new(e))?
);
```

In the above example, `InvalidPathError` might be your own error type. You could also use an error type from the std library.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of this. Will check the documentation next time :)